# TikZ arrow displaces intersection point

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

I am trying to join a curved path to another (two bent edges) using an intersection point as joint, but when adding an arrow with style "-latex" to the second path, the curve is sightly displaced and the intersection point is wrong.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw
  node (A) at (-2,-2) {A}
  node (B) at ( 0,-3) {B}
  node (C) at (-2,-4) {C}
;

\draw [name path=line] (-2,-3.5) -- (-1,-3.5);
\draw [-latex] (A) edge [bend left=45,name path=curve] (C);
\draw [name intersections={of=curve and line}] (B) edge [bend right] (intersection-1) ;
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Follows the image with and without error of the above code.

[image: Curves displacement causes intersection error]

What causes and how do I fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A workaround: `\usetikzlibrary{bending}`. Then the arrow heads of curved arrows are following the curve better:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{bending}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw
  node (A) at (-2,-2) {A}
  node (B) at ( 0,-3) {B}
  node (C) at (-2,-4) {C}
;

\draw [name path=line] (-2,-3.5) -- (-1,-3.5);
\draw [-latex] (A) edge [bend left=45,name path=curve] (C);
\draw [name intersections={of=curve and line}] (B) edge [bend right]
(intersection-1) ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]